# apache disable server signature without httpd.conf and php.ini access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to disable the server signature without access to the httpd.conf?
I can't access to the php.ini too...
I am allowed to edit only the .htaccess

In the .htaccess I tried to add:

1) this, but makes no effect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

2) this, but *"ServerTokens Prod"* gives me an error 500

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Adding only *"ServerSignature Off"*, the signature disappears only from the document, but in the response headers it is still present...

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

ServerTokens is only for server config not .htaccess.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servertokens

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add these lines in .htacess file:

```
ServerSignature Off
Header unset Etag
FileETag none
```